# Visual Studio and SCSS File Formatting Sucks (NOT VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio, sass, formatting

I love working in both VS and VSCode and they both have their benefits. But when I work in VS (Professional) and have to deal with .scss files I hate it.

The formatting is VS sucks for .scss files and is amazing with them in VSCode.

Here is VS that has some green squigglies in certain areas but never stopped formatting until the column names were added:

[image]

Everything after line 11 no longer formats.

And here is VSCode with the same file, looks beautiful, right:

[image]

So what I am hoping for is that there is an extension or tool or something I can use in Visual Studio that at least works better than it does now.

I just wish the VSCode team would rewrite VS. If only for the extension benefits.